# Customised keyboard layout + shortcut key on Ukelele on mac

Tags: unicode

I created a customised keyboard layout for Myanmar Fonts and Language with Ukelele Unicode keyboard layout editor on Mac. But default shortcuts (eg. command + c, command + v) are not working. How can I fix it.